# PREROUTING to LXC container with iptables

Tags: iptables, lxc, ubuntu-18.04, lxd

I've set up two containers with lxd, one with haproxy, pointing to the other with nginx.

I want my server's incoming traffic on port 80 to go to the container with haproxy. This is the rule I've given iptables, but I still cannot access my server from the local network on my laptop (giving the browser the server's local ip).

`-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.148.218.95:80`

I also tried

`$ curl http://127.0.0.1:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 80: Connection refused`

and

`$ curl http://192.168.100.5:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.100.5 port 80: Connection refused`

on the server itself.

Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out (though I am not sure why yet):

```
-A PREROUTING  -d 192.168.100.5/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.148.218.95
-A OUTPUT      -d 192.168.100.5/32 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.148.218.95
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.148.218.95/24 -d 10.0.4.30/32 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: because trying from your host does not count as routing. so there's no prerouting, it's output

Comment: I see. Good point!